# How do I speed up a slow loading rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

We've built www.fastvenues.com using ruby on rails and vue.js. Assets are compiled on production, and I can't see in network tab which one loads slow.

How do we speed this up? If you open it for the first time and try to scroll down it takes about 10 seconds to load. This is un-acceptable for new users and really bad user experience.

How do we solve this? It's difficult to troubleshoot.

Please advise!!!

Comment: There could be a number of reasons, but you could start using miniprofiler gem (https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler), it will help you identify what is taking so long to load/execute.

Comment: Don't use Rails to deliver assets - use a CDN or serve them straight from NGinX. A reverse proxy can also be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

you have quite many pictures, I can see 52, of course it takes time for browser to make all requests, keep in mind at cannot make all requests ant the same time, there are limits.

Try to load only first picture for a restaurant and then download more when user scrolls for example. Also, don't load all the restaurants (I can see 12!), load a few and then again, load more when user scrolls.